# Program/script to plot a neural network in MATLAB with the connection weights

Tags: graphs, matlab, neural-network

I created a neural network in MATLAB, such as `net = feedforwardnet(30);`, which I then trained `[net tr] = train(net,p,t);`.

I'm looking for a program that can:

- plot the neural network like this:

[image]

i.e. displaying the connection weights.

And if possible:

- free
- works on Windows 7 if OS-dependent
- can also display activation functions and threshold
- works for any type of neural network (not just feedforward as in the example)

This could be just a script that converts the network to a .dot file that I could then give to GraphViz.